# sharing drives, folders, and files between kububntu and windows running in virtualbox

Tags: filesystem, usb-drive, drive

am running kubuntu as my host and running windows 7 inside virtualbox.  so far everthing is running fine, but as yet cant get it to let me share external drives, any folders or files on any of the host drives or external drives. which i disperatly need to do and its starting to drive me nuts,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up the shares in Virtual Box under "*Shared Folders*".  If it is running, there is an icon on the status bar (if you're not running full screen), or if not, in the settings dialog.

Choose "*Add Share*", fill in the path and name, select "permanent" and "auto mount" if you always want it mounted.

In Windows, use Explorer to share it normally.  It may be under "VBOXSVR" in the network, depending on how networking is set up.  If you don't see it, you may need to change the way you set up the network under Virtual Box.

Comment: The VirtualBox Guest Additions do not appear to be available on this virtual machine, and shared folders cannot be used without them. To use shared folders inside the virtual machine, please install the Guest Additions if they are not installed, or re-install them if they are not working correctly, by selecting Insert Guest Additions CD image from the Devices menu. If they are installed but the machine is not yet fully started then shared folders will be available once it is.

Comment: Did as stated and i am getting the following message and not sure what it is trying to tell me or how to accomplish it "The VirtualBox Guest Additions do not appear to be available on this virtual machine, and shared folders cannot be used without them. To use shared folders inside the virtual machine, please install the Guest Additions if they are not installed, or re-install them if they are not working correctly, by selecting Insert Guest Additions CD image from the Devices menu. If they are installed but the machine is not yet fully started then shared folders will be available once it is.

Comment: @CharlesHockenberry:  So, do you have the guest additions installed?  If not, you need to get virtualbox-guest-additions-iso, then use the Vbox menu to install it. It's an ISO that mounts in Windows, then gets installed as a Windows program.

Comment: To install the Guest Additions you have to not only load the ISO but also run the installer program from the now newly appearing CD in the guest.